# Validating DataGridView Cells

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview on my form currently. The idea that I'm trying to do is to catch a possible double entry issue when a user edits a cell in the datagridview. I'm supposed to check the field for a duplicate value (which `CheckContestantList` already does by looping through each row and a possible match). On a match, the previous value is supposed to be restored and a messagebox should pop up and warn the user while resetting that field to edit mode.

However, when a user presses the Enter key... the current row indicator moves down by one... and throws everything off. I've already done a bit of reading on the matter but I can't seem to keep the current cell active even if someone presses Enter.

How do I allow for the Enter key to still confirm the enter press but not move down by one row?

```
Private Sub dgvContestantPool_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvContestantPool.CellEndEdit
    ' On the editing of the field, check to see if the value already exists.

    If CheckContestantList(dgvContestantPool.CurrentCell.Value) = True Then

        ' Reset the value to the original value...
        dgvContestantPool.ClearSelection()
        dgvContestantPool.CurrentCell = dgvContestantPool.Rows(intCurrentRow).Cells("ContestantName")
        dgvContestantPool.Rows(intCurrentRow).Selected = True

        dgvContestantPool.CurrentCell.Value = strOldValue
        dgvContestantPool.BeginEdit(True)

        ' Alert the user to try again...
        MessageBox.Show("Entered value already exists in the list, try again or delete the entry.", "INVALID DATA - Already Exists", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        ' Go ahead and let the edit persists.
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub dgvContestantPool_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dgvContestantPool.CellBeginEdit
    strOldValue = dgvContestantPool.CurrentCell.Value
    intCurrentRow = dgvContestantPool.CurrentRow.Index

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong `datagridview` event, if you're gonna validate an input, you can use the `_CellValidating` event.

Here's an example:

```
 Private Sub dgvContestantPool_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgvContestantPool.CellValidating
    If CheckContestantList(dgvContestantPool.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).EditedFormattedValue) = True Then
        'Your code goes here
    End If
 ...
```

Now, for example the cell value is invalid, you can call the 
`e.Cancel = True` in the `cell_validating` event so that the user cannot go to other cells unless the cell value is valid or press the `ESC` key. This will exit the cell and return to its previous/original value.

Comment: Just had to make one change so that the If conditional only checks "dirty" cells but this all works! Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad this will be of help to you. Happy coding.